# subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals

Tags: matlab, indexing

I'm quite new to Matlab/Octave programming, but have this one issue that I can't seem to solve.

I wrote the following which is actually a quite straight forward calculation on an option price using the Black Scholes Formula (just to give you some background). However, I do constantly get the following error msg:

"subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals"

One would think that this explaines it quite nicely and I know there've been questions on it before. The thing that causes troubles, however, is that I am not using any kind of subscript index in my code at all.

Here is my code:

```
function v=BS_LBO_strike_call(s,T,sigma,r,q,l,alpha)
    d1=(log(alpha*l./s) + (r-q-0.5*sigma^2)*T)/(sigma*sqrt(T));

    d2=(log(alpha*l./s) - (r-q+0.5*sigma^2)*T)/(sigma*sqrt(T));

    d3=(log(alpha*l./s) + (r-q+0.5*sigma^2)*T)/(sigma*sqrt(T));

    d4=(log(alpha*l./s) + (r-q-0.5*sigma^2)*T)/(sigma*sqrt(T));

    v = exp(-r*T)*s(0.5*sigma^2./(r-q)*(l./s).^(2*(r-q)./sigma^2).*normcdf(d1) - 0.5*sigma^2./(r-q)*alpha.^(-2*(r-q)./sigma^2).*exp((r-q).*T).*normcdf(d2) + alpha.exp*((r-q).*T).*normcdf(d3) - (l./s).*normcdf(d4));
```

So, I can't seem to figure out what doesn't work out for Octave.

I would highly appreciate if you could maybe shed some light on this. I'm convinced there must be something minor that I overlook

Comment: which is the line associated to the error?

Comment: Is the `alpha.exp*` in the last line a typo in your post or actual code?

Comment: Also, the issue is in this part in the last line: `s(0.5*sigma^2.`. You're using all the stuff to the right of that parenthesis after `s` to index into `s`. Maybe you meant `s*(0.5 *sigma^2`?

Answer (score 2):

The source of your issues lies in your last line. You have the following:

```
v = exp(-r * T) * s(0.5 * sigma^2 ....
```

I *think* that you have omitted an `*` between the `s` and the opening parenthesis because as it is now, everything after that parenthesis is being treated as a subscript into `s`. This is the root cause of the error you are getting because what follows is likely *not* an integer or logical.

There is one other point in that line that is likely going to lead to some errors as well. You have the following as part of that statement.

```
alpha.exp*((r-q).*T) ...
```

Unless `alpha` is a `struct` (I'm sure it's not because you haven't used it that way previously), you will likely want something else besides the `.` between `alpha` and `exp`. Maybe another `*`?